# C program Error - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c, list, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I wanted to practice linked lists and so created a small program that would create a linked list. The program compiles fine using gcc but when i run the program, it works fine till line 13 in main() (scanf("%d", &value1)) after which it prints the error message - "segmentation fault (core dumped)".
I added a print statement in my own testing after line 13 and it doesn't get printed (hence my assumption that the problem arrises after scanf which I dont know why).

So what am I doing wrong?

```
// Creates n numbers of nodes in a linked list where n is the argument 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 25

typedef struct fruits {
    char *name;
    int price;
    struct fruits *next;
}fruits;

int check_format(int argc, char **argv);
fruits *create_node(char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], int value);
void print_nodes(fruits *head);

int check_format(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc == 2) {
        int argument = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (argument > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

fruits *create_node(char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], int value) {

    fruits *newNode = malloc(sizeof(fruits));
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->price = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

void print_nodes(fruits *head) {

    fruits * curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        printf("%s is %d\n", head->name, head->price);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int valid_format = check_format(argc, argv);

    fruits *curr = NULL;
    fruits *head = curr;
    if (valid_format) {
        int number_of_nodes;
        char fruitName[MAX_NAME_LEN] = {""};
        int value1 = 0;

        number_of_nodes = atoi(argv[1]);
        while (number_of_nodes) {

            printf("Enter the fruit name: ");
            scanf("%s", fruitName);

            printf("Enter the fruit price: ");
            scanf("%d", &value1);

            curr = create_node(fruitName, value1);
            curr = curr->next;
            number_of_nodes--;
        }
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", "Usage: ./linked_lists [non-negative integer greater than 0]\n");
    }
    print_nodes(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fruits *newNode = malloc(sizeof(fruits));
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);` allocates memory for the struct but the pointer in it is not pointing to valid memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault because you are accessing `newNode->name` pointer without allocating memory to it in `create_node()`:

```
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
```

Allocate memory to `newNode->name` and then copy `name` to it:

```
newNode->name = malloc(MAX_NAME_LEN);
if (newNode->name == NULL)
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

strcpy(newNode->name, name);
```

With this, make sure to free the memory allocated to `name` pointer before freeing the node.

As an alternative, you can have `name` as `char` array instead of pointer in structure `fruits`:

```
typedef struct fruits {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    ....
    ....
```

With this, you don't need separately allocate/deallocate memory to `name`.

---

Additional:

Follow good programming practice, always check the `malloc` return:

```
fruits *newNode = malloc(sizeof(fruits));
if (newNode == NULL)
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
.....
.....
```

Make sure to free the dynamically allocated memory once you are done with it. I do not see any where you are freeing the list nodes after printing them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 1):

```
fruits *create_node(char name[MAX_NAME_LEN], int value)
{
    fruits *newNode = malloc(sizeof(fruits));
    strcpy(newNode->name, name);
    newNode->price = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    return newNode;
}
```

Here you allocate memory for the struct but not for the name. You have to either allocate memory for the name or change the type from pointer to a fixed size array:

```
typedef struct fruits 
{
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
    int price;
    struct fruits *next;
}fruits;
```